# Words built from $\{0,1,2\}$ with restrictions which are not so easy to accomodate.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, formal-languages

We assume a ternary alphabet $V=\{0,1,2\}$ and are looking for a generating function describing the number of words of $V^*$ fulfilling certain restrictions. The words I am interested in  do *not contain* runs of length $k+1$ (with $k\geq 1$) and  *do contain* the string $1^k2$, i.e. a run of $1$ of length $k$ followed by $2$.

> I'm aware of two techniques which are useful for attacking questions of this kind.
>
> **Smirnow words:** One of them is based upon Smirnov words, which are words with no consecutive equal letters. See e.g. example III.24 in  *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick. The Smirnov words of the three letter alphabet $V$ are represented by the generating function $S(z)$
>   \begin{align*}
> S(z)=\left(1-\frac{3z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}
> \end{align*}
>   Since we are looking for words having maximal runs of $0,1$ and $2$ of length $k$ we substitute
>   \begin{align*}
> z\rightarrow z+z^2+\cdots+z^k=z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}
> \end{align*}
>   Words which *do not contain* runs of length $k+1$ can therefore obtained as
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{3z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}}{1+z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-3z+2z^{k+1}}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> The **[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)** nicely presented by J. Noonan and D. Zeilberger is predestinated if we are looking for words which are not allowed to contain so-called *bad* words. Applying this technique it is easy to find a generating function $T(z)$ which do not contain the *bad word* $1^k2$. According to the formula in page $7$ of the referred paper we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> T(z)=\frac{1}{1-3z+z^{k+1}}
> \end{align*}
>   The generating function $S(z)$ can also be easily obtained with this method. Again according to the formula in page $7$ we get
>   \begin{align*}
> S(z)=\frac{1}{1-3z+3\frac{z^{k+1}(1-z)}{1-z^{k+1}}}=\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-3z+2z^{k+1}}
> \end{align*}

I have problems to derive a generating function which follows the *combined* requirements of counting words which do not contain words with runs of length $k+1$, but contain the substring $1^k2$. Any ideas?

*Note:* This question corresponds to the second part of *[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665513)*.

Comment: @A.S.: Since words have to contain the factor $1^k2$ the length $n$ of words is at least $k+1$. There are no further restrictions.

Comment: 1st order approximation for $k\ll n$ (better for smaller $3^{-k}$). You are approximately looking for words that contain one of $\bar 11^k2$ ($2$ strings of probability $p=3^{-(k+2)}$) and do not contain any of the $x^{k+1}\bar x$ ($6$ strings of probability $p$). The events are practically independent (you only need to subtract the space taken out by the first appearance of the first kind of the string), hence the probability is $$\approx (1-e^{-2p(n-k-1)})e^{-6p(n-3k-2)}$$
and it could be tightened slightly by addressing boundary issues and possibly changing $e^{-ap}$ to $(1-ap)$ for $a=2,6$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fortunately with this problem we can still use a decomposition as with
regular  expressions  which  becomes  less  and  less  useful  as  the
complexity of the language grows.

First introduce  the language of  strings of zeros and  twos having
run length at most $k$ starting with a fixed digit

$$H(z) = z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}
\sum_{q\ge 0} \left(z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}
z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z} \right)^q 
\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}.$$

For  the main generating  function start  the string  with a  chain of
zeros or twos  or the empty string, follow this by  a loop anchored at
blocks of ones and finally add a possible string of ones at the end to
get

$$G(z) = (1+2H(z)) \sum_{q\ge 0}
\left(z\frac{1-z^{k-1}}{1-z} 2 H(z) + z^k (1+v) H(z)\right)^q
\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}.$$

Here we have used $v$ to mark the critical transition $1^k 2.$
To simplify this start with $H(z)$ which yields

$$H(z) = z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-z^2 (1-z^k)^2/(1-z)^2}
\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}
\\ = z \frac{1-z^{k}-z^{k+1}+z^{2k+1}}
{1-2z+2z^{k+2}-z^{2k+2}}.$$

Some simplification on $G(z)$ produces

$$G(z) = 
\frac{(1+2H(z))(1-z^{k+1})}{1-H(z)(2z-2z^k+z^k(1+v)(1-z))/(1-z)}
\frac{1}{1-z}
\\ = \frac{(1+2H(z))(1-z^{k+1})}{1-z-H(z)(2z-2z^k+z^k(1+v)(1-z))}.$$

The reader  is strongly urged to perform  additional simplification on
this. Continuing we seek the generating function

$$Q(z) = \left. G(z) - G(z, 0) \right|_{v=1}.$$

This yields

$$Q(z) =  \frac{(1+2H(z))(1-z^{k+1})}{1-z-H(z)(2z-2z^{k+1})}
- \frac{(1+2H(z))(1-z^{k+1})}{1-z-H(z)(2z-z^k-z^{k+1})}.$$

E.g. we obtain for $k=3$ the following result:
$$Q_3(z) = 
{\frac { \left( {z}^{2}+z+1 \right) {z}^{4} \left( z+1
 \right)  \left( {z}^{2}+1 \right) }{ \left( {z}^{6}+3\,{z}^
{5}+5\,{z}^{4}+5\,{z}^{3}+3\,{z}^{2}+z-1 \right)  \left( 2\,
{z}^{3}+2\,{z}^{2}+2\,z-1 \right) }}.$$

Starting at $n=1$ this yields the sequence

$$0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 21, 80, 287, 993, 3347, 11067, 36055, 
\\ 116089, 370222, 1171353,\ldots$$

We will not show $Q_4(z)$ here. The sequence is
$$0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 21, 81, 296, 1043, 3585, 12095, 
\\ 40221, 132225, 430633, 1391623,\ldots$$

Using $Q_5(z)$ we obtain
$$0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 21, 81, 297, 1052, 3635, 12333,
\\ 41255, 136449, 447147, 1454091,\ldots$$

These sequences  have been verified  with a total  enumeration routine
which is included  with the Maple code for this  problem, which we now
present. The  total enumeration routine  is practical for up  to about
$n=11.$

```
RL :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local ind, d, pos, cur, run, runs, res;

    res := 0;

    for ind from 3^n to 2*3^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, 3);

        cur := -1; pos := 1;
        run := []; runs := [];


        while pos <= n do
            if d[pos] <> cur then
                if nops(run) > 0 then
                    runs := [op(runs), run];
                fi;

                cur := d[pos];
                run := [cur];
            else
                run := [op(run), cur];
            fi;

            pos := pos + 1;
        od;

        runs := [op(runs), run];

        if max(map(r->nops(r), runs)) <= k then
            for pos to nops(runs) -1 do
                run := runs[pos];

                if run[1] = 1 and nops(run) = k
                and runs[pos+1][1] = 2 then
                    break;
                fi;
            od;

            if pos < nops(runs) then
                res := res + 1;
            fi;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;

RNG := (minv, maxv) -> add(z^q, q=minv..maxv);

H :=
proc(k)
    RNG(1,k)*
    sum((RNG(1,k)*RNG(1,k))^q, q=0..infinity)
    *RNG(0,k)
end;


H2 := 
proc(k) 
    z*(1-z^k-z^(k+1)+z^(2*k+1))
    /(1-2*z+2*z^(k+2)-z^(2*k+2));
end;

G := 
proc(k)
    (1+2*H(k))
    *sum((RNG(1,k-1)*2*H(k)
          + z^k*(1+v)*H(k))^q,
         q=0..infinity)
    *RNG(0, k);
end;

G2 := 
proc(k)
    (1+2*H2(k))*(1-z^(k+1))
    /(1-z-H2(k)*(2*z-2*z^k+z^k*(1+v)*(1-z)));
end;

Q :=
proc(k)
    subs(v=1, G(k)-subs(v=0, G(k)));
end;

Q2 :=
proc(k)
    (1+2*H2(k))*(1-z^(k+1))
    /(1-z-H2(k)*(2*z-2*z^(k+1)))
    - (1+2*H2(k))*(1-z^(k+1))
    /(1-z-H2(k)*(2*z-z^k-z^(k+1)));
end;

V :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;

    coeftayl(Q2(k), z=0, n);
end;
```

**Addendum.** Observe that the  initial segment of all these sequences
is in  fact the same.  We  can manually evaluate the  case $n=p$ where
$k+1\le p\le 2k.$ There is the case that the $1^k 2$ block is situated
right  at the  beginning (position  $q=0$). We  may freely  choose the
letters  to the  right  of the  block  which gives  a contribution  of
$3^{p-k-1}.$  (Note that  this stops  working when  $p\gt  2k$ because
forbidden runs may appear to the  right of the block.) If the block is
at position $q$ where $1\le q\le p-k-1$  we must place a zero or a two
just to  the left  of the  block and may  freely choose  the remaining
letters for a contribution  of $2\times 3^{q-1} \times 3^{p-(k+1)-q} =
2 \times 3^{p-k-2}.$ Collecting this into a formula we obtain

$$3^{p-k-1} + 2 \sum_{q=1}^{p-k-1} 3^{q-1} 3^{p-(k+1)-q}
= 3^{p-k-1} + 2 (p-k-1) 3^{p-k-2}.$$

We see that this depends only on the difference $m = p-k$ i.e.

$$3^{m-1} + 2 (m-1) 3^{m-2} = (2m+1) 3^{m-2}$$

so in fact we have the  same initial segment for all $k.$ The sequence
here is

$$1, 5, 21, 81, 297, 1053, 3645, 12393, 41553, 137781, 
\\  452709, 1476225, 4782969,\ldots$$

which is [OEIS A081038](https://oeis.org/A081038).

Comment: Great, Marko! Very nice! This is the kind of answer I was hoping for. I'll check it later in detail, but first of all a big upvote! :-)

Comment: The $n=1$ sequence is `https://oeis.org/A269915` ; `A081038` and `A269915` are similar sequences.

Comment: Yes indeed I added the cases from $k=2$ to $k=5$ to the OEIS.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Hi, Marko! I've started a bounty for you, since your answer was really helpful and instructive. You might want to have a look at my supplementary answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a general method to compute the generating function of any regular language $L$. In your case, $L$ would be $V^* - V^*(0^{k+1} + 1^{k+1} + 2^{k+1} + 1^k)V^*$, if I understood correctly.

The general method works as follows.

**Step 1**. Compute the minimal deterministic automaton of $L$. In your case, this automaton has $3k+1$ states, if I am not wrong.

**Step 2**. Compute an unambiguous regular expression for $L$. Recall that a regular expression $R$ is *unambiguous* if, for every $u \in L(R)$, there is only one $R$-parse of $u$. In other words, a union is unambiguous if and only if it is disjoint, a product $K = K_0K_1 \cdots K_r$ is unambiguous if every word of $K$ has a unique factorisation as $u = u_0u_1 \cdots u_r$, with $u_0 \in K_0$, ..., $u_r \in K_r$ and $K^*$ is unambiguous if the monoid $K^*$ is free of base $K$.

A standard way to obtain an unambiguous regular expression is to use Kleene's algorithm.

**Step 3**. The generating function $s(L)$ of $L$ can be now computed from the unambiguous regular expression by using the rules $s(u) = z^{|u|}$, where $|u|$ denotes the length of a word $u$, $s(L_0 + L_1) = s(L_0) + s(L_1)$, $s(L_0L_1) = s(L_0)s(L_1)$ and $s(L^*) = (1-s(L))^*$.
For instance, if $L = (a + ba + bba + bbb)^*$ (an unambiguous expression), one gets $s(a) = z$, $s(ba) = z^2$, $s(bba) = s(bbb) = z^3$, and finally 
$$
s(L) = \frac{1}{1-(z+z^2+2z^3)}
$$
Coming back to your case, I suggest to treat the cases $k=0, 1$ and $2$ by hand or with the help of a computer and then guess the general formula for any $k$ before trying a more formal proof.

Comment: We are looking for words *containing* $1^k2$. So, the language $\mathcal{L}$ can be written as  $\mathcal{L}=V^*1^k2V^*\setminus V^*\left(0^{k+1}+1^{k+1}+2^{k+1}\right)V^*$.

Comment: This is not my forte but I suspect this regex is problematic as it allows multiple paths through the regex for one and the same string.

Comment: @marko-riedel This is just an expression of the language. As explained in my answer, you have to (1) compute the minimal automaton, (2) find an unambiguous expression for it before getting the generating function in one or several variables (if you want to consider the number of occurrences of each letter instead of the mere length of the word).

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I am in fact familiar with the concept of minimizing a DFA from my studies. In the present case we have $O(k)$ states so running the minimization procedure manually becomes quit a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* The instructive answer from @MarkoRiedel was worth a somewhat in-depth analysis. The outcome of this analysis serves here  as  supplementary information. We consider his approach  in some  detail,  analyse the  connection with **Smirnov words** and  find some simplified representations.

> The essence of his answer is a clever two step decomposition of the language under consideration. As small starter we look at a similar decomposition in a simpler context regarding binary words.
>
> **Binary words**
>
> Non-empty binary words built from an alphabet $\{0,2\}$ and starting  with the letter $0$ admit following characterization. They  decompose into blocks, each block starting with $2$ and followed by zero or more $0$s. The word  starts with one or more $0$s. Here is an example with $|$ indicating the block decomposition.
>
> \begin{align*}
> 000|2|20|200|20|20|2|2000|200|2|2|2|200
> \end{align*}
>
> The language $\mathcal{B}_0$ describing these words is
>
> \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{B}_0=00^*\left(20^*\right)^*
> \end{align*}
>   with star $^*$ denoting zero or more occurrences. The corresponding generating function is
>   \begin{align*}
> B(z)&=\frac{z}{1-z}\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^q\\
> &=\frac{z}{1-z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{1-z}}\\
> &=\frac{z}{1-2z}\\
> &=z+2z^2+4z^3+8z^4+16z^5+32z^6+O(z^7)
> \end{align*}
>   Now let's *exchange* the role of $0$ and $2$ to obtain the language $\mathcal{B}_2$ of words starting with $2$.
>   \begin{align*}
> 222|0|02|022|02|02|0|0222|022|0|0|0|022
> \end{align*}
>
> The language $\mathcal{B}_2$ describing these words is
>
> \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{B}_2=22^*\left(02^*\right)^*
> \end{align*}
>   and the corresponding generating function is the same as before
>   \begin{align*}
> B(z)=\frac{z}{1-2z}
> \end{align*}
>   Observe that *all binary words* can be described as
>   \begin{align*}
> \varepsilon\cup\mathcal{B}_0\cup\mathcal{B}_2\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   which comprises either the empty word or a binary word starting with $0$ or starting with $2$. The generating function is accordingly
>   \begin{align*}
> 1+\frac{2z}{1-2z}&=\frac{1}{1-2z}\\
> &=1+2z+4z^2+8z^3+16z^4+32z^5+O(z^6)
> \end{align*}

We are now well prepared for the first step in the two-step approach of Marko's answer and derive $H(z)$.

> **Binary Smirnov words:**
>
> We again use the binary alphabet $\{0,2\}$. This time we are looking for words which have runs of length maximal $k$. We use a  similar decomposition as we did for the language $\mathcal{B}_0$ above.
>
> We consider zero or more blocks, each block starting with $2$ and followed by at least one or more $0$s. The words start with at least one zero and end with zero or more $2$s. The overall restriction for these words is that the maximum run length is $k$. This sounds complicated, but when we look at the formal language description, let's denote it $\mathcal{H}_0$, it is not that hard.
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{H}_0=00^{<k}\left(22^{<k}00^{<k}\right)^*2^{<{k+1}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> The pattern $00^{<k}$ denotes at least one $0$ followed by zero up to $k-1$ zeros. This way we create non-empty strings of $0$ with run length $\leq k$.
>
> The pattern $\left(22^{<k}00^{<k}\right)^*$ denotes the block decomposition.
>
> The corresponding generating function $H(z)$ for the language $\mathcal{H}_0$ can be directly translated from (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> H(z)&=z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\left(z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}\right)^{2q}\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}\\
> &=z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}\\
> &=z\frac{1-z^k-z^{k+1}+z^{2k+1}}{1-2z+2z^{k+2}-z^{2k+2}}\tag{3}\\
> &=z\frac{1-z^k}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}
> \end{align*}

Note that the representation (3) is stated as $H(z)$ in Marko's answer. It can be further simplified  since numerator and denominator both contain the factor $1-z^{k+1}$.

> As we did in the first section, we exchange the roles of $0$ and $2$, define the language
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{H}_2=22^{<k}\left(00^{<k}22^{<k}\right)^*0^{<{k+1}}
> \end{align*}
>   with the same corresponding generating series $H(z)$
>   \begin{align*}
> H(z)=z\frac{1-z^k}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}
> \end{align*}
>
> If we consider the language consisting of the empty word together with $\mathcal{H}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$
>   \begin{align*}
> \varepsilon\cup\mathcal{H}_0\cup\mathcal{H}_2\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain *all binary words* having run length $\leq k$. Indeed, the generating function is
>   \begin{align*}
> 1+2H(z)&=1+2z\frac{1-z^k}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}\\
> &=\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}
> \end{align*}
>
> The **binary Smirnov words** $B_2(z)$ are the words over a binary alphabet without consecutive equal letters, i.e. having runs of maximum length $1$. Their generating function is specified as (see my question above)
>   \begin{align*}
> B_2(z)&=\left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1+z}{1-z}\\
> &=1+2z+2z^2+2z^3+2z^4+2z^5+O(z^6)
> \end{align*}
>   The generating function for all binary words having runs of length $\leq k$ is consequently
>   \begin{align*}
> B_2\left(z\frac{1-z^{k}}{1-z}\right)&=\frac{1+z\frac{1-z^{k}}{1-z}}{1-z\frac{1-z^{k}}{1-z}}\\
> &=\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}\\
> &=1+2H(z)
> \end{align*}
>   It follows, that the decomposition (4) is indeed the set of all binary words having run length $\leq k$.

Let's have a short look at the binary words with maximum run lengths $k=2,3,4$.
\begin{align*}
B_2\left(z\frac{1-z^{3}}{1-z}\right)&=1+2z+4z^2+6z^3+10z^4+16z^5+O(z^6)\\
B_2\left(z\frac{1-z^{4}}{1-z}\right)&=1+2z+4z^2+8z^3+14z^4+26z^5+O(z^6)\\
B_2\left(z\frac{1-z^{5}}{1-z}\right)&=1+2z+4z^2+8z^3+16z^4+30z^5+O(z^6)\\
\end{align*}

Note that the factor $1+2H(z)$ is also part of the generating function $G(z)$ in Marko Riedels answer, which we are now going to derive. The idea is to use $1+2H(z)$, i.e. the language of all binary words with maximum run length $k$ as *building blocks* when generating *ternary words* with maximum run length $k$.

> **Ternary Smirnov words:**
>
> Remind we are looking for ternary words over the alphabet $\{0,1,2\}$ having maximum run length $\leq k$ and each occurrence of $1^k$ has to be followed by the letter $2$. We start by creating *all ternary words* having maximum run length $\leq k$. The decomposition into $\mathcal{H}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ then enables us, to select precisely the words with $1^k2$ and avoid words with $1^k0$.
>
> We consider the following language 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\varepsilon+\mathcal{H}_0+\mathcal{H}_2\right)\left(11^{<k}\left(\mathcal{H}_0+\mathcal{H}_2\right)\right)^*1^{<k+1}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   starting with a binary, possibly empty string built from the alphabet $\{0,2\}$, followed by zero or more blocks each block starting with at least one $1$ followed by a non-empty string built from the alphabet $\{0,2\}$. A word may end with zero or more $1$s and the run length of each letter is $\leq k$. The corresponding generating function is
>   \begin{align*}
> G(z)&=\left(1+2H(z)\right)\sum_{q=0}^\infty\left(z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}2H(z)\right)^q\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}\tag{6}\\
> &=\left(1+2H(z)\right)\frac{1}{1-z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}2H(z)}\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}\\
> &=\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}\frac{1}{1-z\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}2z\frac{1-z^k}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}}\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}\\
> &=\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-3z+2z^{k+1}}
> \end{align*}

Note that the representation (6) is stated as $G(z)$ in Marko's answer with the marker $v=1$. We can again derive a connection with Smirnov words.

> The *ternary Smirnov words* $B_3(z)$ are the words over a three letter alphabet without consecutive equal letters, i.e. having runs of maximum length $1$. Their generating function is specified as (see my question above)
>   \begin{align*}
> B_3(z)&=\left(1-\frac{3z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1+z}{1-2z}\\
> &=1+3z+6z^2+12z^3+24z^4+48z^5+O(z^6)
> \end{align*}
>   The generating function for all ternary words having runs of length $\leq k$ is consequently
>   \begin{align*}
> B_3\left(z\frac{1-z^{k}}{1-z}\right)&=\frac{1+z\frac{1-z^{k}}{1-z}}{1-2z\frac{1-z^{k}}{1-z}}\\
> &=\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-3z+2z^{k+1}}\\
> &=G(z)
> \end{align*}
>   It follows, that the decomposition (5) is indeed the set of all ternary words having run length $\leq k$.

Let's have a short look at the ternary words with maximum run lengths $k=2,3,4$.
\begin{align*}
B_3\left(z\frac{1-z^{3}}{1-z}\right)&=1+3z+9z^2+24z^3+66z^4+180z^5+O(z^6)\\
B_3\left(z\frac{1-z^{4}}{1-z}\right)&=1+3z+9z^2+27z^3+78z^4+228z^5+O(z^6)\\
B_3\left(z\frac{1-z^{5}}{1-z}\right)&=1+3z+9z^2+27z^3+81z^4+240z^5+O(z^6)\\
\end{align*}

> **Final step:** The words with pattern $1^k2$
>
> The final step is to isolate the words from (5) which contain $1^k2$ and no other runs of $1$ of length $k$. Due to the clever decomposition we can easily identify the language. Starting with the language in (5) we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\varepsilon\right.&\left.+\mathcal{H}_0+\mathcal{H}_2\right)\left(11^{<k}\left(\mathcal{H}_0+\mathcal{H}_2\right)\right)^*1^{<k+1}\\
> &=\left(\varepsilon+\mathcal{H}_0+\mathcal{H}_2\right)\left(11^{<k-1}\left(\mathcal{H}_0+\mathcal{H}_2\right)
> +1^k\left(\mathcal{H}_0+\mathcal{H}_2\right)\right)^*\left(1^{<k}+1^k\right)\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>   From the representation (7) we see we have to skip the strings $1^k\mathcal{H}_0$ in the block and the final string $1^k$. We so obtain the wanted language
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\varepsilon+\mathcal{H}_0+\mathcal{H}_2\right)\left(11^{<k-1}\left(\mathcal{H}_0+\mathcal{H}_2\right)
> +1^k\mathcal{H}_2\right)^*1^{<k}
> \end{align*}
>   The corresponding generating function $A_k(z)$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> A_k(z)&=(1+2H(z))\sum_{q=0}^\infty\left(z\frac{1-z^{k-1}}{1-z}2H(z)+z^kH(z)\right)^q\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}\\
> &=(1+2H(z))
> \frac{1}{1-z\frac{1-z^{k-1}}{1-z}2H(z)+z^kH(z)}\cdot\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}\\
> &=\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}\cdot
> \frac{1}{1-z\frac{1-z^{k-1}}{1-z}2z\frac{1-z^k}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}-z^kz\frac{1-z^k}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}}\cdot\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}\\
> &=\frac{\left(1-z^k\right)\left(1-z^{k+1}\right)}{1-3z+2z^{k+1}+2z^{k+2}-z^{2k+1}-z^{2k+2}}
> \end{align*}
>
> This generating function is slightly different to $Q(z)$ stated by Marko. A reason for it is the different stopping condition of words, since here we also avoid the string $1^k$ at the end of words.

Finally we take a short look at the ternary words with maximum run lengths $k=2,3,4$, containing $1^k2$ but no other string with $1^k$.

\begin{align*}
A_2(x)&=\frac{(1-z^2)(1-z^3)}{1-3z+2z^3+2z^4-z^5-z^6}\\
&=1+3z+8z^2+21z^3+55z^4+145z^5+O(z^6)\\
A_3(x)&=\frac{(1-z^3)(1-z^4)}{1-3z+2z^4+2z^5-z^7-z^8}\\
&=1+3z+9z^2+26z^3+75z^4+217z^5+O(z^6)\\
A_4(x)&=\frac{(1-z^4)(1-z^5)}{1-3z+2z^5+2z^6-z^9-z^10}\\
&=1+3z+8z^2+27z^3+80z^4+237z^5+O(z^6)\\
\end{align*}

The coefficients are verified with code-snippets in R.

Comment: This is nice work:  (+1). Reading your essay it would appear I misunderstood the question, since I permit the run $1^k0.$  That is why I need the indicator variable $v.$ We cannot do without $v$ because we require at least one $1^k 2.$ The variable $v$ counts these transitions and subtracting the terms with $v=0$ yields the GF for at least one $1^k2.$  I will leave my answer as is. Maybe the reader can profit from these two different interpretations.

Comment: I also permit multiple instances of $1^k2$ in my computation.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks Marko. Everything is fine from my point of view. The question was not sufficiently precise formulated regarding the aspect you are addressing. So each answer is valid and quite ok! Many thanks again. Your answer was a boost in good directions! :-)

Comment: You are cordially asked to contribute to the following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767709).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Done.

Comment: That was kind indeed, I was actually suggesting that you solve the problem using coefficient extractor notation as you have done on some other occasions. No worry if the method does not apply here, I am only asking.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: The example looks interesting. I will  have  a  look  at  it  in a few days.  At  the time I'm regrettably busy with other things. Best regards,