# Prove an identity in a Combinatorics method

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

It is a combinatorics proof. Anyone has any idea on how to prove

$$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{l} \sum\limits_{j=0}^i (-1)^j {m-i\choose m-l} {n \choose j}{m-n \choose i-j} = 2^l {m-n \choose l}\;$$

We need to prove this equation holds for all $l$.

I know that $\sum {n \choose j}{m-n \choose i-j}$ equals to ${m \choose i}$ but has no idea if there is a $(-1)^j$, it seems like a PIE but actually not....

Could anyone help me move forward in the process?

Comment: You mean it holds for all $l, m,$ and $n$, right? $i$ and $j$ are indices, but all other variables can be anything?

Comment: $m,n$ are just some constant number and it will holds for all $l,m,n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It   is convenient  to use the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. We   can write    this way
\begin{align*}
[z^m](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{m}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^l&\sum_{j=0}^i(-1)^j\binom{m-i}{m-l}\binom{n}{j}\binom{m-n}{i-j}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^l\binom{m-i}{m-l}\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j[z^j](1+z)^n[u^{i-j}](1+u)^{m-n}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^l\binom{m-i}{m-l}[u^i](1+u)^{m-n}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ju^j[z^j](1+z)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^l\binom{m-i}{m-l}[u^i](1+u)^{m-n}(1-u)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}[z^{m-l}](1+z)^{m-i}[u^i](1+u)^{m-n}(1-u)^n\tag{5}\\
> &=[z^{m-l}](1+z)^m\sum_{i=0}^\infty(1+z)^{-i}[u^i](1+u)^{m-n}(1-u)^n\tag{6}\\
> &=[z^{m-l}](1+z)^m\left(1+\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^{m-n}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^n\tag{7}\\
> &=[z^{m-l}](1+z)^m\cdot\frac{(2+z)^{m-n}}{(1+z)^{m-n}}\cdot\frac{z^n}{(1+z)^n}\\
> &=[z^{m-n-l}](2+z)^{m-n}\\
> &=[z^{m-n-l}]\sum_{j=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-n}{j}2^jz^{m-n-j}\tag{8}\\
> &=2^l\binom{m-n}{l}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply (1) to the binomial coefficients of the inner series and set the upper limit of the index $j$ to $\infty$ without changing anything since we add only zeros.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator, do some rearrangements to prepare for the next step and use the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [u^{p-q}]P(u)=[u^p]u^qP(u)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we apply the *substitution rule*
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_ju^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty u^j[z^j]A(z)\\
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we apply (1) to the binomial coefficient of the first series
- In (6) we do again some rearrangement similar to (3)
- In (7) we apply the *substitution rule* again
- In (8) we select the index $j=l$ to obtain the term with power $m-n-l$

Comment: (+1). It is good to see that you are getting better at these, attacking more involved sums and making considerable progress. I checked it once and it seems sound (will check it several more times). I would say we have the same generating functions but you are not using the theory of complex variables which can be a plus sometimes. Congratulations! We now have a quality page where readability should profit from variety.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks for your nice comment. No doubt, the essence of our answers is the same. It's just a matter of different representations. I admire Egorychevs approach (of course :-)). I found the notation which I've used here the first time in *[Mathematics for the Analysis of Algorithms](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Analysis-Algorithms-Daniel-Greene/dp/0817635157)* by D.H. Greene and D.E. Knuth. They state there that I. Gessel attributed this  *method of coefficients* to Egorychev and so we've come full circle. :-) (+1 btw for your *more original* notation :-))

Comment: As for original notation of course one must be careful. One favorite of mine is to refer to your *substitution rule* as an *annihilated coefficient extractor* which I think accurately represents what is happening. I always use the notation by D. E. Knuth for Stirling numbers of both kinds and for falling and rising factorials, simply because it is intuitive and works well.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: I agree. I like *[this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9205211v1.pdf)* from him regarding *Stirling numbers*. It also gives me a glimpse of what  he may have  thought when he was creating TeX :-)

Comment: The advent of TeX and LaTeX is comparable to Gutenberg but that is stating the obvious.

Comment: Hi, I am a little confused on $(2) \Rightarrow (3)$, I agree that $[u^{p-q}]P(u) = [u^p]u^q P(u)$, but how you can take the $u^q$ out? I am confused for this part...

Comment: @Xiaonan: Let's say it in words. The identity states: The coefficient of $u^{p-q}$ of $P(u)$ is equal to the coefficient of $u^p$ of $P(u)$ multiplied with $u^q$. You might want to check it with small examples like $[x^2](1+x)^4=[x^2](1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4)=6$ and $[x^3]x(1+x)^4=[x^3](x+4x^2+6x^3+4x^4+x^4)=6$. Do you see the relationship?

Comment: Yes...I can understand this example, but I am confused that then you just got $u^j$ out and change from $[u^i] u^j (1+u)^{m-n}$ to $u^j [z^j] \cdots$...would you please explain this briefly?

Comment: From my opinion, $ x [x^3] (1+x)^4 = 4x?$

Comment: @Xiaonan: In (3) we have $[z^j](1+z)^n$. The factor $u^j$ belongs to $[u^i]$ left from it.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Sweet!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$\sum_{p=0}^l\sum_{q=0}^p (-1)^q
{m-p\choose m-l} {n\choose q} {m-n\choose p-q}
= 2^l {m-n\choose l}$$

where $m\ge n$ and $m-n\ge l.$

This is

$$\sum_{p=0}^l {m-p\choose m-l} \sum_{q=0}^p (-1)^q
{n\choose q} {m-n\choose p-q}.$$

Now introduce the integral

$${m-n\choose p-q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{p-q+1}} (1+z)^{m-n} \; dz.$$

Note that  this vanishes when $q\gt p$  so we may extend  the range of
$q$ to infinity, getting for the sum

$$\sum_{p=0}^l {m-p\choose m-l}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{p+1}} (1+z)^{m-n} 
\sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q
{n\choose q} z^q
\; dz
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^l {m-p\choose l-p}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{p+1}} (1+z)^{m-n} 
(1-z)^n
\; dz.$$

Introduce furthermore

$${m-p\choose l-p} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{l-p+1}} (1+w)^{m-p} \; dw.$$

This too vanishes when $p\gt l$ so we may extend $p$ to infinity, getting

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{l+1}} (1+w)^{m} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z} (1+z)^{m-n} 
(1-z)^n
\sum_{p\ge 0} \frac{w^p}{z^p} \frac{1}{(1+w)^p}
\; dz
\; dw.$$

The geometric series converges when $|w/z/(1+w)|\lt 1.$ We get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{l+1}} (1+w)^{m} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z} (1+z)^{m-n} 
(1-z)^n
\frac{1}{1-w/z/(1+w)}
\; dz
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{l+1}} (1+w)^{m} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
(1+z)^{m-n} 
(1-z)^n
\frac{1}{z-w/(1+w)}
\; dz
\; dw.$$

Now from the convergence we  have $|w/(1+w)|<|z|$ which means the pole
at $z=w/(1+w)$  is inside  the contour $|z|=\epsilon.$  Extracting the
residue yields (the pole at zero has disappeared)

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{l+1}} (1+w)^{m} 
\left(1+\frac{w}{1+w}\right)^{m-n}
\left(1-\frac{w}{1+w}\right)^n
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{l+1}}
(1+2w)^{m-n}
\; dw
\\ = 2^l {m-n\choose l}.$$

Comment: This way is brilliant!!!